# How to create quiz result's with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple quiz which contains just six questions using jquery, everything works perfect,

Here is jsfiddle: [quiz demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sdtm3rby/13/)

The final result UI looks like this

[image]

I want the final result's checkboxes to be checked based on questions the user got it right
 Let's assume the user got 4 questions right the final UI should look like this

[image]

Here is my solution

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  var questions = [{
      question: "Whois usa president?",
      choices: ['Trump', 'Biden'],
      correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
      question: "What is the capital of Australia?",
      choices: ["Melbourne", "Sydney", ],
      correctAnswer: 1
    }, {
      question: "Who is the prime minister of the U.K.?",
      choices: ['Tony Blair', 'Kane'],
      correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
      question: "What is the first perfect number?",
      choices: [38, 6, 0],
      correctAnswer: 0
    },
    {
      question: "two plus 1?",
      choices: [1, 2, 3],
      correctAnswer: 1
    },
    {
      question: "Is kenyain africa?",
      choices: ['Yes', 'No'],
      correctAnswer: 0
    }
  ];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('.content'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      $('#warning').text('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
      $('#warning').text('');
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);
    // this is new
    var warningText = $('<p id="warning">');
    qElement.append(warningText);

    return qElement;

  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="checkbox" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if (questionCounter === 1) {
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      } else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    console.log(selections);
    var score = $('<h3>', {
      id: 'question'
    });
    $("#result-input").removeClass('hide-input');
    $("#result-input").addClass('show-input');
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
    // Calculate score and display relevant message
    var percentage = numCorrect / questions.length;
    if (percentage >= 0.9) {
      score.append('Incredible! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
        questions.length + ' questions right!');
    } else if (percentage >= 0.7) {
      score.append('Good job! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
        questions.length + ' questions right!');
    } else if (percentage >= 0.5) {
      score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
        questions.length + ' questions right.');
    } else {
      score.append('You only got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
        questions.length + ' right. Want to try again?');
    }
    return score;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content container-fluid" id="quiz">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="next">Next</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="prev">Prev</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="start">Start Over</button> //checkboxes inputs for the final results
  <ul id="result-input" class="hide-input">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="0">1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="1">2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="2">3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="3">4</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="4">5</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="5">6</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

What do I need to do to achieve what I want? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your displayScore() function, you can select the whole collection of results checkboxes and save them as a variable. Like this: `var checkbox = $('#result-input li').children();`

Then, inside your loop that checks to see if the answers are correct and nested inside your if statement, select a single checkbox from your collection using your iterator variable (i) and set its property to checked. Like this: `$(checkbox[i]).prop('checked', true);`

Here is the updated function:

```
  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
  console.log(selections);
    var score = $('<h3>',{id: 'question'});
    $("#result-input").removeClass('hide-input');
    $("#result-input").addClass('show-input');
    var numCorrect = 0;
    // Selects collection of checkboxes
    var checkbox = $('#result-input li').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
        // Selects single checkbox and sets it to checked if answer is correct.
        $(checkbox[i]).prop('checked', true);
      }
    }
    // Calculate score and display relevant message
    var percentage = numCorrect / questions.length;
    if (percentage >= 0.9){
        score.append('Incredible! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right!');
    }

    else if (percentage >= 0.7){
        score.append('Good job! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right!');
    }

    else if (percentage >= 0.5){
        score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right.');
    }

    else {
        score.append('You only got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right. Want to try again?');
    }
    return score;
  }
});
```

So really, you can achieve this with just 2 added lines of code.

Some further suggestions I would make to improve your app:

1. For the questions, make the options radio buttons instead of checkboxes since checkboxes allow the user to select multiple questions.
2. When user clicks "Start Over" button, hide the results checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will check out , brb

Comment: Very good solution, What about false answers I would like to add (-)  inside a checkbox with wrong answers, what do I need to add here?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add an else to your if statement inside the for loop. Then, inside the else statement, add a class to the checkbox `$(checkbox[i]).addClass(‘wrongAnswer’);`

Using CSS, you can style the checkboxes with that class `.wrongAnswer` to have a minus in it.

Comment: I tried like this `      //append minus icon to unchecked checkboxes
            var uncheckedel = $('<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>');
            console.log(uncheckedel);
            $(checkbox[i]).append(uncheckedel);
         ` but the icon is not showing even though its appended to the input element

Comment: even using ur solution I am getting the following error : `app.js:181 Uncaught TypeError: checkbox[i].addClass is not a function`

Comment: I forgot to add that you need to wrap the checkbox variable in a jquery $ function. It should be: ```$(checkbox[i]).addClass(‘wrongAnswer’);```